# C# Entity Framework SQL Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an EmailHistoryModel :

```
public class EmailHistory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public string OutCome { get; set; }
    public DateTime EmailDeliveredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EmailOpened { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string HtmlEmail { get; set; }
    public string IntegrationDocumentId { get; set; }
    public Rules RulesId { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
}
```

I keep getting an error when trying to access my model. At the moment i am trying to run the following :

```
var emailHistoryTotal = !emailHistory.Any() ? 1 : emailHistory.Count();
```

This keeps giving me the error : "EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier"

I'm not sure what has changed as it was all working ok.....

If i run the following in SQL, it returns ok!?: SELECT * FROM [dbo].[EmailHistory]

In SQL the only columns set to Unique Identifier are the Id, RulesId_Id and the UserId.

The emailHistory is comming from my repository (see below for the method)

```
public IQueryable<EmailHistory> GetEmailHistoryByUser(string userId)
    {           
        return _autoSendContext.EmailHistory.AsQueryable();
    }
```

the _autoSendContext is a global variable to interact with the db

Any help or guidance would be great!

Comment: `Select * From X` is not the same as your `!emailHistory.Any() ...` What are you trying to achive?

Comment: Where are you actually populating the model?

Comment: What exactly is `emailHistory`?

Comment: just by adding 1 and 1 emailHistoryTotal should be an numerical value greater 1.

Comment: You need to post the actual code that calls entity framework.

Comment: please provide proper code for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... it was nothing to do with the email history table. The error was due to Data Migrations, the auto migration was trying to change a field in the database from an NVARCHAR to a unique identifier.

This was the statement the system was trying to run : ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transactions] ALTER COLUMN [CompanyId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL